# Do i need to remove this wp-block-library-css (Gutenberg CSS)?

Tags: html, wordpress, header, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I just want some clarification and advice regarding this tag in WordPress.

This tag is showing in my WordPress head even I'm not using Gutenberg.

```
link rel="stylesheet" id="wp-block-library-css"
```

Is this necessary or required?
Do I need to remove this to improve page speed?
Is there any effect if I remove this tag?

Please enlighten me.

Thank you

Comment: Upvoted. This is coming up in my Pagespeed Insight as "render blocking" and I don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use to remove this stylesheet on websites which are not using Gutenberg.

I don't think there is other effect than removing this stylesheet, you can do it safely.

To go a bit further, you can remove it only for some post types like

```
function remove_wp_block_library_css() {
  if( !is_singular('post') ) {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_wp_block_library_css' );
```

Comment: Hi @Pof, How about the widgets? it is using the block editor? how should we handle it?

Comment: @CarlDaveTampoy Yes, the widgets by default are now using the block editor; you restore access to the classic widget interface through one of the following methods - https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/widgets/opting-out/ You do not need to dequeue any additional CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Gutenberg at all, you can unload styles further more like this :

```
// Unload Gutenberg-related stylesheets.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_block_css', 100 );
function remove_block_css() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' ); // Wordpress core
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library-theme' ); // Wordpress core
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-block-style' ); // WooCommerce
    wp_dequeue_style( 'storefront-gutenberg-blocks' ); // Storefront theme
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. For me the `wp_dequeue_style('wp-block-library');` part alone effectively removed a CSS resource from front-end, which I wanted to get rid of.
Backend unchanged, as I want.
Can you clarify/ confirm that this only modifies the front-end? Also, why is Gutenberg CSS loaded on the front-end anyway? How can I know if my posts use these stylings?